# IF NOT EXISTS In Function PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function which has three If/Then statements before opening a cursor. The If/Then statements check validity prior to opening the cursor.

I would like to add one more If/Then validity check, however, it is a bit more complicated than the others. Below is a sample, and I have block commented what I would like to add:

```
begin
    if not procedure.validation_function (<variable>, <condition>=TRUE) then
        return variable2;
    end if;

   /* if not exists
    (
       SELECT 'x' FROM table1
       WHERE table1_id = variable1_id
       AND trunc(sysdate) < trunc(table1_date + 60)
    ) then
        return variable2;
    end if; */

    open cursor(<argument>);
    fetch cursor into <variable>;
    close cursor;
    return <variable>;


end;
```

My problem is that I come from a T-SQL world, and I am finding in PL/SQL the *if not exists* command does not work. Is there a way  I can, from within the function, have an If NO_DATA_FOUND statement where I utilize SELECT?

Is there a way to nest another function within that, so I can:

```
begin
     SELECT ....
     FROM ....
     WHERE ....
        if NO_DATA_FOUND then
           return variable2;
        end if;
end;
```

Comment: the "if not exists" works as T-SQL, its not so clear what you are asking , i suggest you to simplify your question, I see functions,and ifs, and cursors, and I got messed up of what were you askin'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Exists` condition can be used only in SQL statement, it cannot be used directly in PL/SQL. There are several options:

- Using `case`  expression with `exists` condition inside a `select` statement:

  ```
  SQL> declare
    2    l_exists number(1);
    3  begin
    4    select case
    5             when exists(select 1
    6                           from employees
    7                          where department_id = 1)
    8             then 1
    9             else 0
   10           end into l_exists
   11      from dual;
   12  
   13     if (l_exists = 1)
   14     then
   15       dbms_output.put_line('exists');
   16     else
   17       dbms_output.put_line(q'[doesn't exist]');
   18     end if;
   19  end;
   20  /

   doesn't exist

   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
  ```
- Or (`rownum` is needed to guarantee that the only one record will be returned if there are several records meet matching condition):

  ```
  SQL> declare
    2    l_exists number;
    3  begin
    4  
    5    select 1
    6      into l_exists
    7      from employees
    8     where department_id = 100
    9       and rownum = 1;
   10  
   11     dbms_output.put_line('exists');
   12  
   13  exception
   14    when no_data_found
   15    then dbms_output.put_line(q'[doesn't exist]');
   16  end;
   17  /

   exists

   PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
  ```

Comment: If EMPLOYEES is a sizable table there are likely to be real benefits to testing for mere existence rather than counting all the matching rows.  But in any case, the EXISTS variant expresses our intent more clearly: we don't care *how many* rows match in EMPLOYEES providing there's at least one, so why bother with the count?

Comment: @APC Of course, APC, it wouldn't be wise to count every matching row if we are testing only for existence at least one record. I've modified the second method in the answer to make it more efficient.

Comment: The case statement worked very well for me. Sorry for the late acceptance! Thanks!