# SQL statement ignored on IF clause. ERROR IN TRIGGER

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

So we're building an APEX app based on an existing DB. This trigger is supposed to prevent it from having COMERCIAIS who are also ADMINISTRATIVOS. COMERCIAL is a view of COMERCIAIS. But we're getting this error:

```
ERROR at line 2: PL/SQL statement ignored.
```

It appears that the error is in the IF EXPRESSION...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER id_in_admin_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON COMERCIAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(:new.id not in (SELECT id from ADMINISTRATIVOS))
   THEN
     INSERT INTO COMERCIAIS values(:new.id,:new.N_CONTRATOS);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: WHICH RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Not sure what that is but we're using APEX (Application Express 4.0.1.00.03) from ORACLE...

Comment: See this question: **[IF NOT EXISTS In Function PLSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503408/if-not-exists-in-function-plsql)**

Comment: Would suggest ypercube make this an answer, since it's pretty much the answer.