# If Not Exists Insert fails with error Unknown command for If Not Exists statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below Oracle Command to insert a row but before that I am supposed to check whether that row exists in table and if exists do nothing.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Value1 ='Value 1' AND Value2='Value 2' AND Value3='Value 3' AND Value4='Value 4')
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO table1
(
  Value1,
  Value2,
  Value3,
  Value4,
  Value5
)
VALUES
(
  'Value 1',
  'Value 2',
  'Value 3',
  'Value 4',
  'Value 5'
)
END;
```

I feel that above statement should hold good however it throws

> **Error starting at line : 7 in command - IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM
>   table1 WHERE Value1='Value 1' AND
>   Value2='Value 2' AND Value3='Value 3' AND
>   Value4='Value 4') Error report - Unknown Command**

The error thrown is not much helpful here to dig more on this problem and am newbie on this. Hope to find some help on this.

Comment: Why you tagged mysql?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have If Existst statement. You need to change your logic based on rowcount

Comment: @Hawk.. It suggested.. removed it..

Comment: @Harsh.. I think it has.. Just saw from **[this link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_28533877.html)**

Comment: Exists cannot be directly used in PL/SQL. Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503408/if-not-exists-in-function-plsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest possible approach (not the most efficient) would be to do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_cnt pls_integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM table_name
   WHERE col1 = 'value1'
     AND col2 = 'value2'
     ...

  IF( l_cnt = 0 )
  THEN
    <<your insert>>
  END IF;
END;
```

You can do the `insert`, catch the exception, and ignore it (I assume there is a unique constraint that would prevent duplicate rows otherwise you'll have a serious race condition no matter how you implement the check)

```
BEGIN
  <<your insert>>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN
    NULL; -- Ignore the exception, we don't have to insert the row
END;
```

Or you could do a `merge`.  Assuming that you're on 10g, the `WHEN MATCHED` clause becomes optional

```
MERGE INTO table_name dest
  USING( SELECT 'value 1' col1, 
                'value 2' col2,
                'value 3' col3,
                'value 4' col4
           FROM dual ) src
     ON( src.col1 = dest.col1 and
         src.col2 = dest.col2 and
         src.col3 = dest.col3 and
         src.col4 = dest.col4 )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
     VALUES( src.col1, src.col2, src.col3, src.col4 );
```

Or you could do an `insert`

```
INSERT INTO table_name( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'
    FROM dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                       FROM table_name
                      WHERE col1 = 'value1' 
                        AND col2 = 'value2'
                        AND col3 = 'value3'
                        AND col4 = 'value4' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [MERGE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement) for this kind of problems. It is pure SQL, simple and straightforward. In your example, it would be like this:

```
MERGE table1 T1
USING (SELECT 'Value 1' Value1, 'Value 2' Value2, 'Value 3' Value3, 'Value 4' Value4 FROM DUAL) T2
ON (T1.Value1 = T2.Value1
AND T1.Value2 = T2.Value2
AND T1.Value3 = T2.Value3
AND T1.Value4 = T2.Value4)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (T2.Value1, T2.Value2, T2.Value3, T2.Value4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and idea.. :)

Comment: I didn't know you could simply omit the "when matched."  Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit of a hack, but I was trying to think of a way to use a `merge` statement into Oracle but didn't know how to divert the "if not exists" to null:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5)
with cte as (
  select
    'Value 1' as v1, 'Value 2' as v2, 'Value 3' as v3,
    'Value 4' as v4, 'Value 5' as v5
  from dual
)
select *
from cte
where not exists (
  select null
  from table1
  where
    Value1 = cte.v1 and
    Value2 = cte.v2 and
    Value3 = cte.v3 and
    Value4 = cte.v4 and
    Value5 = cte.v5
)
```